# Xcode7.1でプロジェクトにSyphon.framework追加時にエラーが発生します。

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, xcode7

Xcode7.1でSyphon.framework追加時にエラーが発生します。

全然、意味不明ながら以下の手順に従ってやったつもりなんですが、

1.Add the framework to your Xcode project.
The simplest way is to drag it to the Frameworks group in the project window.
Link your application with Syphon at build time.

2.Add the framework to the Link Binary With Libraries build phase of your application's target.
Copy the framework into your application's bundle.

3.Add a new Copy Files build phase to your application's target.
Select Frameworks as the destination.
Drag the Syphon framework into the build phase.

エラーメッセージは以下、

ld: framework not found Syphon
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
[image: スクリーンショット1]

環境はOS10.10.5です。
どうしたらコンパイルが通って実行できるでしょうか。よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

おそらくFramework Search Pathsの設定が抜けているのでフレームワークを見つけることができていないのだと思います。

プロジェクトのビルド設定の「Framework Search Paths」にフレームワークがある場所のディレクトリを指定します。

ただ、おそらくそれは難しいと思いますので、

最初からやり直して、プロジェクトのターゲットを選択して、「Embedded Binaries」（下記のスクリーンショットの場所）にフレームワークをドラッグ＆ドロップするのが最も簡単な方法です。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: ありがとうございます。それも試してみたんですが、相変わらず同じエラーが表示されます。
確かにFramework Search Pathsを見ると空なんですが、そこからどうしたらいいのか全く分からなくてすごく困ってます。